# Throwing exception when array is out of bounds

Tags: c++

I have a matrix class, that uses [][] to access elements. When one (or both) indexes are out of bounds, I have to throw CIndexException. It's a class that stores text in this format "Invalid index [a][b]", where a and b are numbers.

This is my current implementation of CIndexException class

```
class CIndexException
{
    string text;
public:
    CIndexException (int a, int b)
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Invalid index [";
        oss << a;
        oss << "][";
        oss << b;
        oss < "]";

        text = oss.str();
     }

     string get() const
     {
         return text;
     }
};
```

Matrix is represented as a 2D array of doubles, it is initialized in constructor:

```
CMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    colls = c;
    rows = r;
    mat = new double * [rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new double [colls];
        for (int j = 0; j < colls; j++)
            mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

To get single element, I overloaded [] operator like this:

```
double * operator[] (int x) const
{
    return mat[x];
}
```

When I type a[2][3], this function resolves the first [], returns pointer to an array and the second [] gets resolved as usual.

I can easily check if the first index is out of bounds, but I have trouble checking for the second one. I thought of creating second class, MatrixRow, that represents one row of matrix. Then I would have array of MatrixRows. To get [][] working, both of those classes would have overloaded operator[]. That way I would be able to check both indexes, but I have no idea how to "join" them into one exception. How can I report both indices in the exception object while using this design?

Comment: You've already answered your question, you need to make a `MatrixRow` class, overload the `[]` operator on that, and you're done. What's the problem?

Comment: I see no question marks.

Comment: @antonijn -- the problem is that the `MatrixRow` class needs to report both indices used in the exception, but normally it would only know the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with your `MatrixRow` solution, but pass the index of the row to each `MatrixRow` as a constructor argument. The `MatrixRow` can save that number, and use it in any exception messages it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `operator()()` instead of `operator[]()`. See this [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-subscript-op.html). All what you need this link considers.

Comment: That's just ugly. Those matrices use a special non-C++ syntax for indexing.

Comment: `m[i][j]` says: "Hello `m(i,j)`. You are so ugly, but you work so good and your design is much simpler. Why?"

Comment: The same application will likely also use 1D arrays (vectors). Will they also overload operator()? Now they're different from native arrays and std::vector; confusion ensues.